# What does $GL(V) \cong GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I have proven that $GL(V) \cong GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, where $GL(V)=\{f: V \rightarrow V | \text{ f is bijectiv and linear}\}$ and $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the set of $n \times n$ complex matrices with non-zero determinant and with the operation multiplication given as multiplication of matrices.

Why is it important to show that $GL(V) \cong GL_n(\mathbb{C})$? What do we use this for? I know im not specific in my questions. But why do we want to show this?

Comment: I am assuming that $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ over the complex numbers. The isomorphism is given by fixing a base of $V$ and is not canonical. So we are often in the "practice" either in the situation of making computations, which is good for people that like to compute like me, or in the situation where we are developing theories and invariants in a "universal form" (using functors on $V$ like taking wedge products or symmetric tensor products or more complicated stuff and taktind specific parts of them, which is good for people like me. And sometimes we need a bridge...

Answer (score 4):

$GL(V)$ is much harder to visualise than $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, and the isomorphism says they are the same. So you can work with 'easy objects' instead. In this concrete example, this means that you fix a basis and do the computations w.r.t. this basis.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of $GL(V)$ are linear maps, in particular applications $V\to V$. They can be quite complicated a priori.

The elements of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ are matrices, so literally tables of numbers : those seem very easy, and computations are more likely to be tractable with them than with linear maps.

On the other hand, $V$ has in general no preferred basis, so reasoning with $GL(V)$ can be seen as working "coordinate-free"; and can sometimes be more conceptual than some raw matrix computations, so it can also have its benefits.

The isomorphism you note allows for a dictionary between the two approaches; if you need to compute stuff, pick a basis, an isomorphism, and compute with matrices. If you need to do some conceptual work, forget the bases, and work "geometrically" with $V$.

Comment: Yes, this was pretty much exactly my reasoning for including the exercise in the notes the OP is working through.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting example.
Consider $P_n$, of polynomials with complex coefficients of degree $n-1$. $P_n$ is a $n$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. The derivative map $f(x) \mapsto f'(x)$ is a linear operator on $P_n$.

The theorem shows that there is some $n\times n$ matrix $M$ with the following property: for all $c_1, ..., c_n, d_1, ..., d_n$: $$M \times [c_1, ..., c_n ]^T = [d_1, ..., d_n ]^T \iff \frac{d}{dx}\{c_1 + c_2 x + c_3 x^2 + ... + c_n x^{n-1}\} = \{d_1 + d_2 x + d_3 x^2 + ... + d_n x^{n-1}\}$$

In other words, taking a derivative is a specific form of matrix multiplication. More generally, all (finite dimensional) linear transformations are matrix multiplications.